# Why does this javascript variable not get set into a cookie in php?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have the javascript function below which sends the variable 'widgets' to a php file via an ajax call. If I then send the variable widgets back to the html document and echo it out it displays on the clientside screen correctly. BUT when it is sent to php I try to set it into a cookie and the cookie doesn't get set. Here is the javascript function:

```
function positions(){
    var widgets = '';
    var col = document.getElementById('col');
    for(i = 0; i < col.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var str1 = col.childNodes[i].className;
        if(str1 && str1.match('widget')) widgets+='&c[1]['+i+']='+col.childNodes[i].id;
    }

xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/ajaxwidgetpositions.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("widgetpositions="+widgets);
var e = document.getElementById('widget_data');
e.innerHTML += '<p><a>' +widgets + '</a></p>';
xmlhttp.send(null);
return true;
}
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php
$widgetpositions = $_POST["widgetpositions"];
setcookie("widgetss", $widgetpositions);
?>
```

For what it's worth, the javascript varibale 'widgets' has the form:

```
&c[1][1]=widget_5&c[1][2]=widget_11&c[1][4]=widget_1&c[1][6]=widget_13
&c[2][2]=widget_6&c[2][4]=widget_10&c[2][6]=widget_2&c[2][8]=widget_3
&c[3][3]=widget_7&c[3][5]=widget_12&c[3][7]=widget_8
```

I cut out some of the function positions code to make it more readable so 'widgets'above is a bit longer than you might expect, but that is the form it takes. Maybe that is too much to store in a cookie?

Does anyone know why it's not getting set to a cookie? Please help.

Comment: And as a note... It is no way near to much data for your cookie. Firefox and Opera used to max out around 4090 and IE took even more. Not sure if this is valid info, but Apache used to error out if the cookie was larger than 8190 bytes and the request would not be served at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the data is posted an recived on the PHP side? Check this with `var_dump($_POST)`.

If it is, are you sure your session doesn't expire or something? Since you don't have an expiration time when you set your cookie it will get wiped when the session dies.

Try with

```
<?php
$widgetpositions = $_POST["widgetpositions"];
setcookie("widgetss", $widgetpositions, time()+60*60);
?>
```

Does the cookie still not set?

Comment: I added var_dump($_POST) to the php file and nothing happens when I refresh the page so does that mean the data isn't being received PHP side?

Comment: To add, the cookie does not set.

Comment: If you added this to your script that receives the post then YES, your post data is NOT being sent to the server.

You could use JQuery to send your data easily: `$.post("foobar.php", { firstname: "Foo", lastname: "Bar" } );`

Comment: Ok. so I would have to add   
  $.post("ajaxwidgetpositions.php", { widgetpositions: widgets } );   and delete everything between the for statement and the return true part of my javascript code? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your data it would probably be ok. You must include the JQuery library to your file though and it might be wise to JSON encode the data. Google for "JQuery post ajax json ecode" or similar and you will fins what you need.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i set and delete cookies without having problem in IE

```
  //Always use domain and path to control your cookies better.
  //otherwise in IE you can have problem.

  //setcookie
  $domain = "domain.com"; //without subdomain.
  $domain = "/path_of_this_file/"; //without subdomain.

  $widgetpositions = $_POST["widgetpositions"]; 
  setcookie("widgetss", $widgetpositions, time()+3600, $path, $domain, false); 

  //delete cookie
  setcookie("widgetss", '', time()-31536001, $path, $domain, false); 

?>
```